# Mocking A Class Returned By A Function In Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class hierarchy with a bunch of wrappers that I am trying to test. I have created a simple version of what I am trying to do below but cannot seem to figure out where my problem is.

**ClassA.py**

```
import ClassB


class ClassA:
    key = None

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello World from ClassA!'

    def set_key_from_class_d(self):
        class_b = ClassB()
        class_d = class_b.get_class_d()
        self.key = class_d.key
```

**ClassB.py**

```
import ClassC


class ClassB:
    class_c = None

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello World from ClassB'
        self.class_c = ClassC()

    def get_class_d(self):
        return self.class_c.get_class_d()
```

**ClassC.py**

```
import ClassD


class classC:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello World from ClassC!'

    def get_class_d(self):
        return ClassD()
```

**ClassD.py**

```
class ClassD:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello World from ClassD!'
        self.key = 'my_key'
```

**test_classes.py**

```
import mock
import unittest
from ClassA import ClassA


class TestClasses(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('ClassA.ClassB')
    def test_classes(self, mock_class_b):
        mock_class_d = mock.MagicMock()
        mock_class_d.key = 'test_key_here'
        mock_class_b.return_value = mock.MagicMock()
        mock_class_b.get_class_d.return_value = mock_class_d
        class_a_instance = ClassA()
        class_a_instance.set_key_from_class_d()
        print 'mock_class_d.key in test is: %s' % mock_class_d.key
        self.assertEqual(class_a_instance.key, 'test_key_here')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'hello'
    unittest.main()
```

When I run `python test_classes.py` I get the following output:

```
> python test_classes.py
hello
Hello World from ClassA!
mock_class_d.key in test is: test_key_here
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_classes (__main__.TestClasses)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rybridges/misc_code/test_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "test_classes.py", line 17, in test_classes
    self.assertEqual(class_a_instance.key, 'test_key_here')
AssertionError: <MagicMock name='ClassB().get_class_d().key'     id='4535940752'> != 'test_key_here'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Obviously something is not quite right with the way in which I am mocking this stuff. I don't understand why when I print mock_class_d.key inside of the test it says what I want, but once the functions get called it gets lost along the way somewhere. What am I doing wrong?
Would prefer to leave ClassA - ClassD alone if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: You basically replace all important class (and with their methods) with mocks. There is nearly no original object to test anymore. The name `test_classes` raises a flag already: A unittest tests *one* unit (like on function). So write one test per method you want to test and more if you have to test different behavior in the unit itself. This separation allows you to only mock what is outside the unit.

Comment: Hey I appreciate the reply. Unfortunately I am really not interested in testing these methods one at a time. Admittedly, this is more of an integration test. And for me on my project, an integration test on this functionality is most useful.